# records get with duplicate id in mysql ( in condition ) ? any query to get

Tags: mysql

my query is

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE post_id in (2,12,2)
```

============================

output get

post_id 2,12

=============================

output want

post_id 2,12,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be cos the table add auto-increment? and this doesn't make sense for mysql.

```
SELECT pa.post_id FROM posts pa WHERE pa.post_id in (2,12)
UNION ALL
SELECT pb.post_id FROM posts pb WHERE pb.post_id = 2
```

UNION ALL add the duplicate row but dunno if you want that output. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have the same value two times(2). Only the first one is taken into consideration.

Comment: why would you like this solution?

Comment: because some time display tow times post but my common function return only one post